# Parentheses in thebibliography environment

Tags: bibliographies, brackets

I want to change the default square brackets in the entries of the thebibliography environment to parentheses.

Sample:

```
% sample.tex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Sample]{Sample} Sample.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

but I want:

```
(Sample) Sample
```

Is it possible to change it in "thebibliography" environment?

Comment: Without an MWE that's difficult to answer. You could use for example the natbib package, see reference sheet (options section) here http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

Comment: But I think natbib doesn't work without BibTeX.

Comment: Well, there is the point with the MWE, i couldn't check that against your idea and didn't know, your approach should work without BibTeX. Could you please add a complete MWE? edit: I think it actually might, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: I use BibTeX and Natbib...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the standard classes you have to change the internal command `\@biblabel` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Sample]{Sample} Sample.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```